# jdbc connection using thin driver

Tags: java, oracle, classpath, jdbc

i am connecting oracle 10g xe with java but getting the exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Even if i have included the classpath of driver i.e ojdbc14.jar
if i have set wrong classpath please tell me the correct way to set the classpath

Answer (score 1):

note that running a **JAR** (double-click ou "java -jar file.jar") does not use the CLASSPATH environment variable

[How Classes are Found](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

In that case - running a JAR - you must set the Class-Path attribute in the manifest file

[JAR File Specification](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.  I believe the oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver was deprecated and removed between 9i and 10g.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are running your application. Normally you can set the classpath via the env var CLASSPATH, or the command-line-switch -cp.

Please provide more details of your environment.

Comment: i m using windows xp
and setting classpath env.var as
%classpath%;I:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application as a Web Application in **Tomcat**, the **ojdbc14.jar** must be in, I believe, **{tomcat_home}/server/lib**.  That or {tomcat_home}/common/lib... but I'm pretty sure it's server/lib.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in a jar file called classes12.jar in oracle app server 9.0.4.